# Julia: Array manipulation

Tags: arrays, data-structures, julia

I'm having trouble with removing a specific element from an array in Julia.

I have an array of Job objects, each with their own attributes, and as a user answers a questionnaire, I want to remove the jobs from the array that does not match the users preferences.

```
jobs = [retail, construction, nurse, programmer, engineer, law]
```

Basically, if, for example, the user does not to work outside, I would want to remove construction.

after looking at the julia documentation, there does not seem to be a method for simply removing a specified value from a basic array. Is there any other way to do this using another data structure?

Comment: There's `deleteat!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a `Set` is a good option for a data structure for this purpose, e.g.

```
jobs = Set(["retail", "construction", "nurse", "programmer"])

delete!(jobs, "nurse")
push!(jobs, "teacher")
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

```
jobs = filter(x->x != "construction",jobs)
```

Another method:

```
splice!(jobs,findfirst(x->x=="construction",jobs)
```

A third option:

```
jobs = jobs[map(x->x!="construction",jobs)]
```

I've assumed the array elements are strings, although in the question they appear as Job typed variables, but the conditions are all general predicates - so will work with appropriate modification.